# Telegram geolocation

Tags: geolocation, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have an idea to use a telegram bot for food ordering from a smartphone. So, you have a menu, prices, there is a payment gateway. This part seems clear to me.

I was wondering if there any way to get a geolocation information inside telegram? So smartphone owner location is sent automatically.

The alternative I see are:

- writing address thru telegram (too much work and probably restaurant has to call back);
- Install a small Android/iOS app just to send a location to the service. Kinda feels awkward, but a little better that first option.

Maybe you can see better ways, perhaps telegram already got some related functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, there is. I'll write 2 ways how it can be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On some step (don't do it too early) you can send a button with the `request_location` field set to `true`.

When the user presses that button, Telegram asks the user if he wants to share his location with the bot.

The user then sends a location. Note that the user could also spoof the location.

Comment: On desktop app (windows os) `request_location` button not working.

Comment: Yes, but that's a problem with Telegram Desktop. It even displays a message: "Sorry, the location sharing is currently unavailable in Telegram Desktop."

Comment: What do you mean by "don't do it too early"?

Comment: Users are scared if the first question is "please share your location"

Comment: is that a one time share? or is it possible to share thenceforth?

Comment: It's a one-time share. You can always request the location again.